# Cannot read property 'Elm' of undefined while using Elm 0.19 in Electron

Tags: electron, elm

I’m experimenting Elm 0.19 with Electron building a simple Elm app (based on the Counter example) in Electron. When I run `electron-forge start`, I get an error that says `Cannot read property 'Elm' of undefined` highlighting `scope[‘Elm’]`  part of the elm.js file.

```
function _Platform_export(exports) {
    scope[‘Elm’] ? _Platform_mergeExportsDebug(‘Elm’, scope[‘Elm’], exports) : scope[‘Elm’] = exports;
}
```

The interesting thing is that the exact same files (Main.elm, index.html) open up just fine (showing the counter as expected), if I run `elm-live Main.elm --open -- --output=elm.js` instead.

So it appears that `this` passed to elm.js in Electron is undefined, which then caused  `scope` to be undefined.

The Chrome Dev Tool shows the `scope` variable passed to elm.js is `undefined` in the case of the Electron app. In the case of elm-live, that value was the `Window` object.

elm.js

```
(function(scope){
'use strict';

 --- omitted ----

    var author$project$Main$main = elm$browser$Browser$sandbox({ init: author$project$Main$init, update: author$project$Main$update, view: author$project$Main$view });
    _Platform_export({ 'Main': { 'init': author$project$Main$main(elm$json$Json$Decode$succeed(_Utils_Tuple0))(0) } });
})(undefined);
```

elm.js? [sm]

```
(function(scope){
'use strict';

 --- omitted ----

var author$project$Main$main = elm$browser$Browser$sandbox(
    {init: author$project$Main$init, update: author$project$Main$update, view: author$project$Main$view});
_Platform_export({'Main':{'init':author$project$Main$main(
    elm$json$Json$Decode$succeed(_Utils_Tuple0))(0)}});}(this));
```

Error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Elm' of undefined
    at _Platform_export (elm.js:1949)
    at elm.js:4004
    at elm.js:4005
index.html:44 Uncaught ReferenceError: Elm is not defined
    at index.html:44
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="elm"></div>
</body>
<script src="./elm.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = Elm.Main.init({
        node: document.getElementById('elm')
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Main.elm

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)


main =
  Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }


-- MODEL

type alias Model = Int

init : Model
init =
  0


-- UPDATE

type Msg = Increment | Decrement

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Increment ->
      model + 1

    Decrement ->
      model - 1


-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (String.fromInt model) ]
    , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Elm #electron channel on Slack, I saw a discussion about this issue and here is a recap for anyone interested.

1. The issue is that 'this' is not defined in the electron renderer
2. This causes `scope` within Elm runtime to be `undefined`.
3. Possible work-around is

   - uglify the compiled elm code using the instructions at https://elm-lang.org/0.19.0/optimize
   - or change (this) to (this||window) at the bottom of the compiled elm.js file (Opened an issue here https://github.com/elm/core/issues/998)